# Independence of FLT over weak systems

Tags: number-theory, proof-theory, reverse-math

It is known that Fermat's last theorem can be proven in finite-order arithmetic (e.g. accoridng to [this](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/mathematician-puts-fermats-last-theorem-axiomatic-diet) site). This is still an extremely high upper bound on proof complexity (for example, compared to Friedman's conjecture that it's provable in EFA).

I've been wondering, are there any (nontrivial) *lower* bounds for such possible proof? For example, is it possibly known if FLT is independent of $I\Delta_0$ theory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious: Did McLarty provide a different stand-alone  proof of FLT, or did he make an argument such as "because there exists Wiles' proof, FLT holds in certain models and hence there must exist a finite-order arithmetic proof"? (I.e., similar to the well-known "if FLT is undecideable then it holds for 'the' natural numbers as there cannot be a counterexample")

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I believe McLarty sketched an actual proof in finite order arithmetic. I'm unsure though, the results are beyond what I can understand.